# Dynamic domain depending on user selection (odoo 8)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, odoo

### What I need:

I want to make one field for user to select a category of partners. After he made that I want to let him to select a partner from a selected category. How could I achieve that?

---

### What I did:

I have the fallowing fields:

```
partner_categories = fields.Many2one('res.partner.category', string="Partners Categories")
partner_category_name = fields.Char(related='partner_categories.name', string="Choosen category name")
partner_adress = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Partner from selected category")
```

In the xml i have these lines:

```
<field name="partner_categories"/>
<field name="partner_category_name"/>
<field name="partner_adress" domain="[('res.partner.category','=', 'partner_category_name')]" attrs="{'invisible': [('partner_category_name', '=', 'False')]}"/>
```

But that doesn't work. I'm getting error:

```
ValueError: Invalid field 'res.partner.category' in leaf "&lt;osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('res.partner.category', 'ilike', 'partner_category_name') on res_partner (ctx: )>"
```

Afcourse it is normal because I can't inherit `res.partner` module so that I could access all its fields, so `res.partner.category` is unknown field for my module. But how could I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `category_id` field use for set category in `res_partner` then you can write..

For that you need to write `partner_category` in view... if you don't want then make it invisible.

```
 <field name="partner_category"/>
 <field name="partner_adress" domain="[('category_id','=',partner_categories)]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `ValueError: Invalid field 'res.partner.category' ...` because `'res.partner.category'` isn't a field, it is a model...Due like a said you in your other Q, you need to use `onchange` method, first when a user select a category fired a onchange, inside it, fill the other field(`partner_adress`) filtering by the category selected. Let me search a good example for you and `I'll be back` to edit this answer!